# How to edit List view from Detail view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am searching for a solution to edit List data from a detail view. In HomeVC, I have a List, in this List I pass detail data and a function to update this list. But it goes some errors:

```
class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var vouchers: [Voucher] = []
    func fetchVouchers () {
        let request = APIEndpoint.getHomeVouchers()
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let resData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(VouchersResponse.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.vouchers = resData.data.promotions
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct HomeVC: View {

    @ObservedObject var VM = HomeViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List {
           ForEach (VM.vouchers) { voucher in
                ModalLink (destination: VoucherDetailView(voucher: voucher, didEditVoucher: { v in
                    self.VM.vouchers.first(where: { $0.id == v.id })?.purchased = true
                })) {
                    VoucherCard(voucher: voucher).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30, height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 30) * 1)
                }.padding(.top, 15)
           }
    }
}
```

This is my detail view, I tried to update Voucher by set `purchased` is `True`, then update in `List` in `HomeVC`

```
struct VoucherDetailView: View {
    @State var voucher: Voucher
    var didEditVoucher: (Voucher) -> ()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.voucher.purchased = true
                self.didEditVoucher(self.voucher) 
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The errors:

> Cannot assign to property: function call returns immutable value

in line of code:

`self.VM.vouchers.first(where: { $0.id == v.id })?.purchased = true`

Photo:

[image]

Comment: can you please show us, where you declare VM? Usually in SwiftUI you cannot change variables, because the view is a struct. you just can change it, if it is a Binding, State or environmentObject...or something similar.

Comment: @Chris I show  `HomeViewModel ` as `VM` in the first code section above. I just dont understand why this line of code `self.VM.vouchers.first(where: { $0.id == v.id })?.purchased = true` go error `Cannot assign to property: function call returns immutable value`

Answer (score 1):

this is because first is a getter only:

```
var first: Element? { get }
```

it is not because of VM or observableObject.

you could try like this:

```
var id = self.VM.vouchers.first(where: { $0.id == "a" })?.id
getVoucher(by id: id).purchased = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the best solution for this data flow in SwiftUI for this issue:

https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/07/03/managing-data-flow-in-swiftui/

In order to edit List data from a Detail View, you have to use a `struct` to map the index in List, then you handle data in this `struct`

```
struct IndexedCollection<Base: RandomAccessCollection>: RandomAccessCollection {
    typealias Index = Base.Index
    typealias Element = (index: Index, element: Base.Element)

    let base: Base

    var startIndex: Index { base.startIndex }

    var endIndex: Index { base.endIndex }

    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        base.index(after: i)
    }

    func index(before i: Index) -> Index {
        base.index(before: i)
    }

    func index(_ i: Index, offsetBy distance: Int) -> Index {
        base.index(i, offsetBy: distance)
    }

    subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        (index: position, element: base[position])
    }
}

extension RandomAccessCollection {
    func indexed() -> IndexedCollection<Self> {
        IndexedCollection(base: self)
    }
}
```

You don’t need to post notifications or observe key-value to indicate changes in your User Interface, all you need is using correct Property Wrapper provided by SwiftUI.